# Accessing mongoose schema array with body-parser

Tags: node.js, mongoose, body-parser

Here is an example schema:

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new schema ({
username: {type: String},
hobby: [{
    indoor: {
        type: {type: String},
        description: {type: String}
    },
    outdoor: {
        type: {type: String},
        description: {type: String}
    }

}]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

So, a very simple schema. It asks for a user name, and then it asks for a user to list their hobbies, and is split between indoor and outdoor hobbies, and inside of an array.

Using body-parser, I could get to a user name in a form input like this:

```
var user = new User();
user.username = req.body.username;
```

That's simple enough. But how do I get to the hobbies inside of the array? I've tried doing:

```
user.hobby.indoor.type = req.body.type
```

But this doesn't work; it just gives me an error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did end up finding the answer to my problem. Here is an example of what to do:

```
var user = new User();
user.username = req.body.username;
user.hobby = {{
    indoor: {
        type: req.body.type,
        description: req.body.description
    }
}];
```

And that's how you can get to a property inside of an array.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will help you access your key properly. As hobby is an array, you need to provide an index for fetching its objects. Dot notation works with objects

`user.hobby[0].indoor.type`

Js Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x18nyd2e/

Comment: Adding the [0] just doesn't seem to work... I still get errors. You mentioned that I "need to provide an index for fetching its objects"; I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that.

Comment: You cannot access array objects without specifying the array index. To access the indoor object you need to specify the 0th index at which indoor object is placed. I am updating a link where you can find the solution.

Comment: So I've been playing around with your jsfiddle, and got it working fine. But I still can't get it to apply to my form fields. Here is a jsfiddle that shows my form field, my schema, and my router.post: https://jsfiddle.net/4qq3hzr9/3/  ...It will retrieve the username just fine, but it wont retrieve 'type' from the form field.